# Parametersing Function in switch statement in c++

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

I tried to pass a string to a function , but not able to do so;

I have initially tried to make the str[100] variable global but incorrect output;

also i tried to pass str as parameter to the function but the same incorrect result.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;


char str[100];

void nwrds(char s)
{
    int i=0,len=0,cnt=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    cout<<"The number of words in the string are "<<cnt+1<<endl;
}

void hyp(char s)
{
    int i=0,len=0,cnt=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            str[i]='-';
        }
    }

    cout<<"The changed string is :-  "<<str<<endl;
}


main()
{

    int i=0,len=0,cnt=0;


    cout<<"Enter the string :-  ";
    cin.getline(str,100);
    cout<<endl;

    len=strlen (str);

    cout<<"You have entered :-"<<str<<"\n\n"<<endl;

    int p;

    cout<<"Enter what do you want to do "<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Count number of words "<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Replace space by hyphen "<<endl;
    cin>>p;

    switch (p)
    {
        case 1:  nwrds(*str); break;
        case 2:  hyp(*str); break;  
        default : cout<<"Do nothing "<<endl; break;

    }

}
```

For instance if my string is"I am cool"
The output  I am getting when I enter 1 is
The number of words in the string are 1. So what am I doing wrong!!!

Comment: Your first for loop evaluates to `for(i=0;i<0;i++)` You should also declare the `int i` in the for loop itself.

Comment: Same for the second loop: `len` should be initialized to the size of the strings, not zero.

Comment: you have `len` set to 0 in both functions .. those loops are not executed.

Comment: On top of that: you're passing single characters to your functions: `void nwrds(char s)`

Comment: What is 's' doing there? Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: No, started off with the `s` as function parameter and then changed to using the global `str` variable and it still wouldn't work - as per Neil Kirk's answer.

Comment: I'd like to see the C++ tag removed from this question.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked!!! I got it that I was not passing the len declaration where it was actually used. THANKS.        Just one more question, can we count number of words without counting spaces, what is enter a string as "Hello (2 or 3 spaces between)      world" rather than "Hello world"

Answer (score 1):

You should change your function parameters like below :

```
void nwrds(char* s, int len)
{
    int i=0 ....
```

And then call the function like this :

```
nwrds(str, len);
```

Inside your function use input variable "s" instead of global "str", and this way you may put your "str" variable inside your main function, removing it from global variables. Having global variables is a bad idea...

One additional point: you have to pass a string length as a parameter to the function (together with the string itself) because you pass the string as a pointer, and there is no other way to get to know the string length inside the function.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked!!! I got it that I was not passing the len declaration where it was actually used. THANKSJust one more question, can we count number of words without counting spaces, what is enter a string as "Hello world" rather than "Hello world"

Comment: Just one more question, can we count number of words without counting spaces, what is enter a string as "Hello(2 or 3 spaces between) world" rather than "Hello world"

Comment: @SameerSawla Nonsense! Global variables and parameters can well have the same name.